# Can only concatenate error, can't work out what to do

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I'm trying to make an electronic menu service for a diner, one of the required functions is to be able to add to the menu. I'm not very good at all of the debugging side of things and I'm now getting an error saying

> Can only concatenate list (not string) to list

I don't know what it means and have tried everything to get rid of the error but it won't go away. can you guys help me out?

```
menu = (["all day breakfast large, £5.50", "all day breafast small, £3.50", "hot dog, £3.00", "burger, £4.00", "cheese burger, £4.25", "chicken goujons, £3.50", "fries, £1.75", "salad, £2.20", "milkshake, £2.20", "soft drinks, £1.30", "still water, £0.90", "sparkling water, £0.90"])
for i in menu:
    text_file.write(i)
    

elif menu_editing == "add":
    add_item_number = (input("please enter what number you would like to add the new item. "))
    add_item_name = (input("""please enter the name of the item like this: all day breakfast large""")) 
    add_item_price = (input("please enter the price of the item you wish to add without the pound sign. "))
    menu == menu + "",add_item_name,"£"+add_item_price[add_item_number]
```

Comment: The error tells you that you cannot concatenate (join-together) an object of type `list` with an object of type `str`. Could you please update your code and so that we can see how you create `menu`?

Comment: first use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to see what you have in varaibles. It is called `print debuging`. And then you will know what you try to concatenate.

Comment: The code as shown literally makes no sense – please [edit] the question to include a [mcve] including the full error message and tracebacl. Code cannot have an ``elif`` following a ``for`` (only following an ``if``). ``menu == menu + "",add_item_name, ...`` is a tuple that is thrown away; the last element ``add_item_price[add_item_number]`` attempts to index a string by a string, which is an error. There are lots of redundant parentheses obscuring what goes on, key names are undefined (``text_file``, ``menu_editing``). See the [ask] page how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Is `menu` variable a list? If it is, you should use `menu.append(<stuff you want to append as string here>)`

Also, you get three string back from your input, what are you trying to achieve with `add_item_price[add_item_number]`? From the little information that we have, I assume you want to display the price * itemnumber? You can do that like this:

`menu.append(f"{add_item_name}, £ {int(add_item_price)*int(add_item_number)}")`

Note the `f" "` notation, which allows for reference to variables in string using accolades.